# Questions of production readiness of software libraries

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions of whether an open source programming library is production ready off topic on SO?

Comment: Yes....SO is for practical, specific, answerable programming questions. The subject you mention is off-topic by several definitons.

Comment: Is it off-topic on SO itself, or here? It seems some confused. Look at the down votes. :)
Let me try again, this times a little differerent: Are questions of questions of whether an open source programming library is production ready off topic on SO off topic on meta.SO?

Comment: Off-topic for SO...questions about questions are fine for Meta

Comment: Note that meta voting is different from other StackOverflow sites. A down-vote here does not mean that someone thinks you've posted a poor question, but rather just that they disagree with your question's premise.

Comment: Sometimes I think that in future every question topic will be off-topic on every stack exchange site

Comment: @Lol4t0 well ,that would make it much easier to identify bad questions for closure.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with a question like that.  If I get to pick and choose: the answers will be irrelevant a month later.

Comment: Pick another @Hans Passant since that you picked can be the case for many on topic questions as well.

Comment: And also the question in the link is different. So that is not a duplicate. Yes I have learned by some means the thing in this question is broad and off topic for to be asked in SO. Thanks for relevant answers and comments.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Such a question would probably be too broad and definitely primarily opinion based.

The answer to such question will highly depend on the classification of the type of product to use it in, the company expectations, the specific part of the library maybe, etc. Also, the answer is almost instantly outdated when there is another version released. Such questions aren't knowledge base material.

Comment: It's probably opinion-based even within the library authors: developers "It's fine!", test/QA;" It's shit!", top management: "SHIP IT NOW".